# ASP.Net Export CSVHelper File - Cleanup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

New to csvhelper, trying to make sure that I clean up\close all connections once user downloads file, not sure if I've done this right, could anyone advise what I need to do?

```
public ActionResult ExportClients()
{
    var token = new Token(this.User.Identity.Name);
    var clients =_clientService.Get(toekn.Id);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);

    csvWriter.WriteRecords(clients);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return File(memoryStream, "text/csv","clients.csv");                    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemoryStream`, `StreamWriter` and `CsvWriter` all implement [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). So, let's take them one at a time:

#### First, the `MemoryStream`

`FileStreamResult` [will dispose of the provided stream for you](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs#L29), which is the result of calling `File` at the end of the controller.

#### Next up, the `StreamWriter`

Ordinarily, you'd need to dispose of this yourself, with e.g. a `using` statement. In your example, disposing of `CsvWriter` will actually do this for you. However, there's a catch. By default:

> The StreamWriter object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamWriter.Dispose is called.

There's a [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows for the underlying `Stream` to be left open. You'll need to use this; otherwise, the `MemoryStream` will get disposed before the `FileStreamResult` gets hold of it and you'll get the dreaded "object already disposed" exception.

#### Finally, the `CsvWriter`

This is the simplest case - You can just dispose of it yourself, using e.g. a `using` statement.

---

Here's the revelant code:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true);

using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(clients);
    // No need to flush as the StreamWriter's Dispose takes care of that.
}

memoryStream.Position = 0;

return File(memoryStream, "text/csv","clients.csv");
```

Unfortunately, there's no constructor for `StreamWriter` that allows you to provide just the `Stream` and the `leaveOpen` flag, so you have to use the one I've used above. The `1024` is the default value, but the `Encoding.UTF8` is [slightly different](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,c73af21c3340883d). It should suffice, but perhaps someone else will come along and point out how that can be better handled.

Comment: As an additional note: Writing to a `MemoryStream` might be a little inefficient for large files (the data gets written to memory and then copied out to the HTTP response). With ASP.NET, you can write directly to the response stream, which would cut out the need for your interim `MemoryStream`. I think that falls outside of the scope of this question on disposing of resources, but it's useful to consider.